# Got stuck at onclick toward canvas element

Tags: javascript, onclick, canvasjs

I am working on a page that can creating different colours. This is not fully code yet, as it stuck now.

Basically it is intent to have multiple circles bouncing inside the canvas with different colours assigned to, however, the "onclick" can't trigger the circle on the canvas. Would be great if information website also share to me.

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1100;
var h = 600;

setUpCanvas();

document.querySelector("#button").onclick=click;

function click(){
    var a1 = document.querySelector("#a1").value;
    var a2 = document.querySelector("#a2").value;
    var a3 = document.querySelector("#a3").value;
    var o1 = {
        "x": rand(w),
        "dx": randn(10),
        "y": rand(h),
        "dy": randn(10),
        "r": 30,
        "red": document.querySelector("#Red1").value,
        "green": document.querySelector("#Green1").value,
        "blue": document.querySelector("#Blue1").value,
        "a": a1/100,
        "n": document.querySelector("#Ncircle1").value
    };
    var o2 = {
        "x": rand(w),
        "dx": randn(10),
        "y": rand(h),
        "dy": randn(10),
        "r": 30,
        "red": document.querySelector("#Red2").value,
        "green": document.querySelector("#Green2").value,
        "blue": document.querySelector("#Blue2").value,
        "a": a2/100,
        "n": document.querySelector("#Ncircle2").value
    };
    var o3 = {
        "x": rand(w),
        "dx": randn(10),
        "y": rand(h),
        "dy": randn(10),
        "r": 30,
        "red": document.querySelector("#Red3").value,
        "green": document.querySelector("#Green3").value,
        "blue": document.querySelector("#Blue3").value,
        "a": a3/100,
        "n": document.querySelector("#Ncircle3").value
    };

    for(i=0; i<o1.n; i++){
        circle(o1)
    };
    
    for(i=0; i<o2.n; i++){
        circle(o2)
    };

    for(i=0; i<o3.n; i++){
        circle(o3)
    };

    o1.x += o1.dx;
    o1.y += o1.dy;
    if(o1.x > w - o1.r || o1.x < 0){
        o1.x *= -1;
    };
    if(o1.y < h - o1.r || o1.y < 0){
        o1.y *= -1;
    };

    o2.x += o2.dx;
    o2.y += o2.dy;
    if(o2.x > w - o2.r || o2.x < 0){
        o2.x *= -1;
    };
    if(o2.y < h - o2.r || o2.y < 0){
        o2.y *= -1;
    };

    o3.x += o3.dx;
    o3.y += o3.dy;
    if(o3.x > w - o3.r || o3.x < 0){
        o3.x *= -1;
    };
    if(o3.y < h - o3.r || o3.y < 0){
        o3.y *= -1;
    };

    if(o1.n < 0 ||o2.n<0||o3.n<0){
        console.log("Number can not be negative.")
    };

    circleColour(o1);
    circleColour(o2);
    circleColour(o3);

    console.log(o1.n,o1.red,o1.green,o1.blue,o1.a);
}

function circle(x,y,r,red,green,blue,a){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+red+","+green+","+blue+","+a+")";
    ctx.fill();
}

function circleColour(o){
    for(i=0; i<o.n; i++){
        circle(o)
        updateData(o);
    }
}

function randi(r){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*r)
}

function rand(r){
    return Math.random()*r
}

function randn(r){
    return Math.random()*r - r/2
}

function setUpCanvas(){
    canvas = document.querySelector("#mycanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.border = "5px solid blue";
}

console.log("Colour Mix");
```

```css
#container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colourmix.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Colour Mix</h1>
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
            <form id="myform">
                <label for="Ncircle1">Number of Group 1 circles</label>
                <input type="number" id="Ncircle1">
                <label for="Red1">Red</label>
                <input type="number" id="Red1">
                <label for="Green1">Green</label>
                <input type="number" id="Green1">
                <label for="Blue1">Blue</label>
                <input type="number" id="Blue1">
                <label for="a1">Opacity</label>
                <input type="number" id="a1">

                <label for="Ncircle2">Number of Group 2 circles</label>
                <input type="number" id="Ncircle2">
                <label for="Red2">Red</label>
                <input type="number" id="Red2">
                <label for="Green2">Green</label>
                <input type="number" id="Green2">
                <label for="Blue2">Blue</label>
                <input type="number" id="Blue2">
                <label for="a2">Opacity</label>
                <input type="number" id="a2">

                <label for="Ncircle3">Number of Group 3 circles</label>
                <input type="number" id="Ncircle3">
                <label for="Red3">Red</label>
                <input type="number" id="Red3">
                <label for="Green3">Green</label>
                <input type="number" id="Green3">
                <label for="Blue3">Blue</label>
                <input type="number" id="Blue3">
                <label for="a3">Opacity</label>
                <input type="number" id="a3">

                <!-- <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                <button type="button" onclick="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="colourmix.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would implement JQuery. You would simply need to add this line to your HTML before you include your JS file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

This would include Jquery allowing you to do the following:

```
$("button").on( "click", click );
```

This code is run when any element that is of type button is clicked and calls the function **click()**. This will work but if it doesn't you can always change the button to have an id and reference it as such in JQuery

```
$("#button").on( "click", click );   // '#' means id, '.' means class and nothing means type
```

Hope this helps! If you have any problems, feel free to comment and I will try my best to respond asap.